# Heroku Django App Very Slow

Tags: python, django, amazon-rds, heroku

I have a Django app deployed on Heroku and it is VERY slow!

I'm making small queries and I'm waiting a long time (10-15+ seconds to load 12 items (a 41KB request).

I'm using the Insomnia tool to test queries. When I make a 3.3KB request to my local server, it takes 400ms, whereas the same request to my Heroku deployed server takes 2400ms. I don't know if this is normal, but 6X slower seems like a lot.

My database is Amazon RDS.

It seems like there must be something wrong with the Heroku side, but I don't know where to look. Is there anything in particular I can test or check to learn more about what's causing this bottleneck?

Thanks for any information! Much appreciated. I've spent a lot of time looking online with no progress so far!

Comment: Hi. Is oracle your database?

Comment: @JRichardsz My database is hosted on Amazon RDS and it's PostgreSQL. Does that answer your question? Sorry I'm new to database and AWS stuff!

Comment: I had similar performance issues with oracle rds. In my case was due to internals oracle configurations which caused that localhost times and server times were different. I mean, app in my localhost to rds oracle takes 2 seconds, but same app in my cloud connected to the same app , takes 5minutes or more. Check this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41841491/why-oracle-stored-procedure-execution-time-is-greatly-increased-depending-on-how

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue ended up being some middleware I had installed in my Django app called Silk, which ironically I had installed to help me diagnose my app speed. This is pretty specific, but I hope it helps someone!